# Config.xml file for windows 7.8 mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

Windows Phone 7.8 is supported till Phonegap 2.9 
From Phonegap 3.0 its for WIndows Phone 8

I researched on net and found that there is need to crate config.xml file in project root directory where inex.html file is present.

Can anybody tell me what code to write in config.xml file?

Comment: check the platform guide for windowd phone 7 : http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_wp7_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%207%20Platform%20Guide (adding lines in config.xml is for if you're using `phonegap build` to build your app in the cloud) or with the cli: `cordova platform add wp7`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a new Windows Phone 7 project via:

```
$ phonegap create Test
$ phonegap platform add wp7
$ phonegap build
```

Then when created, look in `./platforms/wp7/www` for `config.xml` and you can get an idea there what is needed. In reality, you will just need to edit config.xml in the root folder - you should not need to create this or do any heavy changes to it...